# Extract unique HTML tags from a document

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I have an HTML document in R, and I want to extract a list of unique tags from that document with a count of their frequency of occurrence.

I could loop through every possible tag as follows, but was hoping for a solution that didn't require a pre-defined list of tags:

```
library('XML')
url <- 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array'
doc <- htmlParse(url)
all_tags <- c('//p', '//a', '//b', '//u', '//i')
counts <- sapply(all_tags, function(x) length(xpathSApply(doc, x)))
free(doc)
```

Comment: Hmm `table(xpathSApply(doc, "//*", xmlName))`?

Comment: @lukeA Perfect.  Make your comment an answer!

Comment: Agreed that @lukeA shld post his as an answer and that his should be accepted as the answer. I only posted the Hadleyverse version for folks using `xml2` and deliberately didn't include the `XML` / `xpathSApply` in hopes Luke would post an answer.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic XML package version could look like this:

```
tab <- table(xpathSApply(doc, "//*", xmlName))
tab[c('p', 'a', 'b', 'u', 'i')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hadleyverse version (but with a reversion to base if necessary):

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array'
doc <- read_html(url)
tags <- xml_name(xml_find_all(doc, "//*"))

# base version
sort(table(tags))

## tags
##     body     form       h1     head     html    title      sub       h3        i noscript 
##        1        1        1        1        1        1        2        3        3        3 
##       h4       h2       th     link       hr       ol       ul       em    input        b 
##        4        5        5        7        8       10       11       12       12       14 
##   script     meta      img       br      pre   strong    tbody    table     code       li 
##       16       17       26       27       41       43       55       79      104      115 
##       tr        p       td      div        a     span 
##      127      150      268      358      371      423 

# hadleyverse
arrange(count(data_frame(tag=tags), tag), desc(n))

## Source: local data frame [36 x 2]
## 
##      tag   n
## 1   span 423
## 2      a 371
## 3    div 358
## 4     td 268
## 5      p 150
## 6     tr 127
## 7     li 115
## 8   code 104
## 9  table  79
## 10 tbody  55
## ..   ... ...
```